# Document is occupied by openoffice

Tags: java, openoffice.org

I used openoffice to convert doc to pdf but sometimes it did not work, and then the document was occupied even though i closed the connection:

```
try {
    converter.convert(sourceFile, pdfFile);
} catch(Exception e){
    return "error";
} finally {
    connection.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're closing only the connection not the converter. Close the converter and it'll work.

Comment: I`m sorry that i am new to this, i did not find the method to close the converter.Could you tell me how to close it.Thank you very much.

Comment: Try converter.close() or check for similar methods that are displayed.

Comment: I use the OpenOfficeDocumentConverter() class but it does not have such methods,

Comment: Have you checked all available methods? Maybe dispose() is available. Can't find a useful documentation of that class.

Comment: I find the api, but it does not have such methods.Thank you.